# Personalize Caliburn.Micro Views path

Tags: c#, caliburn.micro

I'm new with caliburn and building a simple app, but i want to change where i put my views

my project look like:

```
Project/
  Model/
    ...
  View/
    TestView.xaml
  ViewModel/
    TestViewModel.cs
  App.xaml 
  AppBootstrapper.cs
```

but with this i get a `cannot find view for Project.ViewModel.TextViewModel`. obviously if I put the view into the same directory, the application works perfectly but i want to cahnge the location where i can configure that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The folders the Views and ViewModels are in are namespace specific.
Change the folder View to Views and ViewModel to ViewModels, and update the .cs and .xaml for that new namespace.

Check this link out for further information:
http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=View/ViewModel%20Naming%20Conventions

Specifically, in your case here, header: "Naming Conventions for Namespace of a Type"